# Centered one-line python code in markdown

Tags: html, markdown, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to center a code in markdown (used in JupyterLab). Here is the code I use

```
<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:1em;"> 
`code template`
</span> </div>
```

But this code keeps showing `` ` `` at the beginning and end of this simple snippet. Any suggestion on solving this problem is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Markdown generally is not processed in HTML block-level elements like `<div>`s](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block.

But you can still use HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:1em;"> 
    <code>code template</code>
</span> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you; this is exactly what I needed.